# Running MVC application under Cassini

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cassini

I am trying to run Asp.Net MVC applications using [Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) but when i launch my application, all I get is directory listing and not the results of my default controller/action.
What I am I missing?

I need to mention that WebForms apps are running fine.

Comment: how does you global.asax.cs file look like?

Comment: @tugberk: the default global.asax you get when you create an MVC app. I mean I cant ran ANY MVC application under Cassini.

Comment: hmm, this is weird. are you on VS2010?

Comment: @tugberk:Yes. But I am not talking about the build-in version of Cassini. I am talking about the version downloadable here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any good reason for using standalone cassini ? I am not quite sure how "registration" of MVC stuff (route handlers, httphandler.. ) works with it - maybe it knows only about handlers for webforms. Do you know about the new IIS Express ? very lightweight and powerfull, full compatibility with IIS, maybe you could try it instead.

Comment: I need an Http server I can embed in my own application to serve a few dynamic files. The point is to have an app the user can just install and run without the need for configurations and separate setups. I have checked out IIS Express and the functionality of [HWC](http://www.awesomeideas.net/page/IIS7-Hostable-WebCore.aspx) but they don't suit my needs